# Why Java Cleaner is not working in this example?

Tags: java

I'm using Java 11. I have a class that uses the deprecated finalize method, and I want to start using 'Cleaner' instead.

This is the class I use:

```
public class TempFile2 extends File
{
    private static final Cleaner cleaner = Cleaner.create();

    public TempFile2(String pathname)
    {
        super(pathname);
        cleaner.register(this, cleanAction());
    }

    private Runnable cleanAction() {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("inside cleanAction");
            if (this.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("deleting " + this.getName());
                this.delete();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And using it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String filePath = "<some_path>";
    TempFile2 tempFile2 = new TempFile2(filePath);
    tempFile2.createNewFile();
    tempFile2 = null;
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Why is the cleanAction() method inside TempFile2 not called? (by the way, I know that System.gc() doesn't guarantee GC to run, but I know that in my example it runs since I'm also monitoring with VisualVM and trigger GC from there, and verify it runs).

When I run the same except TempFile2 is using a finalize() method then the finalize() is called.

Comment: Your Runnable stores a **strong** reference to your TempFile object. Therefore, I don't see how it could be garbage collected, since the cleaner keeps a reference to the cleaning action, which, in your case, keeps a reference to the temp file.

Comment: So how to modify my TempFile2 object to delete the file using Cleaner? (using finalize() works even though it also uses a reference to the same object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing exactly what the javadoc of [Cleaner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) tells you not to do:

> Note that the cleaning action must not refer to the object being
> registered. If so, the object will not become phantom reachable and
> the cleaning action will not be invoked automatically.

It is not recommended to use things like lambdas or (anonymous) inner classes, because that will (or in the case of lambdas, could) retain a strong reference. That is exactly what happens here because your lambda references `this`, which is the instance of `TempFile2`.

You cannot write a direct equivalent of your old finalizer. Either consider calling `File#deleteOnExit()` in the constructor (which might be too long a delay for long running programs), or register the path as a string or `Path` in your cleanup action, and do the cleanup action with that.

For example, something like this:

```java
public class TempFile2 extends File {

    private static final Cleaner cleaner = Cleaner.create();

    public TempFile2(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
        cleaner.register(this, new CleanupFileAction(this.toPath()));
    }

    private static class CleanupFileAction implements Runnable {

        private final Path filePath;

        private CleanupFileAction(Path filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if the `Path` object created by `File.toPath` would somehow retain a reference to the original `TempFile2` instance, this wouldn't work either, but luckily that is not how `Path` and (`File#toPath()`) is implemented.

As an aside, the general advice when it comes to `Cleaner` instances, is to create only one for your application or library, and not one for each class, unless you think so many cleanup actions will get triggered by your code that a single thread is not sufficient to keep up.

Comment: Thank you Mark. This indeed works. (I read the Cleaner Java doc, but wasn't aware that I'm doing what it tells not to do). Anyway, I understand now.

Comment: BTW, the code can be shortened a few lines by declaring `CleanupFileAction` as a record (if you're using Java 16 or higher).